# Best language for a daemon application?

Tags: daemon

I was looking to create an application to track certain MySQL data in real time. I.e. when a new person registers, etc. What would be the best language to do this in? C++, C,Java? I'm looking for whatever language will have the smallest memory footprint.

Comment: Assembler would probably give you the smallest memory footprint, but are you sure that you don't have other important considerations such as cost, development time and maintainability?

Comment: It will be mainly for my own use.  I'm looking to create this application to gain exposure to more programming languages.  I can do something like what I want with PHP, but PHP is obviously not a good language to daemonize with..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are making a web application with users registering your server will have to run constantly and probably store to a DB...so implicitly real time. As far as what you would write such a site in - I think Java/J2EE, Ruby, or the new and hot Node.JS are all viable, along with numerous others.

...and you could always use cron to run every few seconds too, heh.

Does this address your question?

Comment: crons can not run on seconds, minimum step is a minute ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**Of course Java/J2EE, Ruby is better for you.**